# Angularjs: Resolve url param via server response

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have working code like this

*app.ts*

```
function getYear(): number {
    const date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
}


$urlRouterProvider.when("/", `/year/${getYear()}`);

 $stateProvider.state("/", {
        url: "/"
    }).state("app", {
        url: "/year/{year:int}",
        controller: "AppController as ctrl",
        templateUrl: "templates/application.html",
        requireADLogin: true,
        params: {
            year: getYear()
        }
    })
```

Bun now it's requiered to get the 'year' param from the server.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("/", {
        url: "/"
    }).state("app", {
        url: "/year/{year:int}",
        controller: "AppController as ctrl",
        templateUrl: "templates/application.html",
        requireADLogin: true,           
        resolve: {
           year: ["YearService", (yearService: services.YearService) => {
                    return yearService.GetYear();
                  }]
        }
    })
```

But this just hangs the page with anormous amount of watcher exceptions.

Also I was thinking about:

```
$stateProvider.state("/", {
        url: "/"
    }).state("app", {
        url: "/year/{year:int}",
        controller: "AppController as ctrl",
        templateUrl: "templates/application.html",
        requireADLogin: true,
        params: {
            year: function(){
              //Here is the question
              //How to resolve services.YearService?
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: try your params like this.. params: {
  year: { type: 'int', raw: true }
}

Comment: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up replacing `getYear()` function with syncronous server call like this:

```
 function getYear(): number {
        if (!window["initialYear"]) {
            var year = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "api/year/initial",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            window["initialYear"] = parseInt(year);
        }

        return window["initialYear"];
    }
```

It's not the best way because it's syncronous and stops Angular processing to make the request.

It's better to use `index.html` file with a `<script/>` reference to your API method which should return `JSONP` with a callback function which is placed in the `index.html` file above `<script/>` tag with API call. And in the callback function you need to initialize `window["initialYear"]` which will be then available in your `app.ts`